# Questions about how to use a third party plugin for programming

Tags: support, asking-questions, scope

I want to ask a question about "how do I" using Resharper. It's not a programming question (ie, it's not about a language, more about a configuration within Resharper) so I guess off topic here, but, 'here' is the most likely place to get an answer as it's a programming tool.

Is this on or off topic?

Comment: What is the question going to be about exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programming tools are on-topic on Stack Overflow. So a question about Resharper would certainly fit on SO. There are already [more than 1700 questions about Resharper on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper). Your question might already be answered there.

Your example "How do I use Resharper" though is far too vague, but if you have more specific questions your can certainly ask them here.

Comment: Thank you, this is great to know.